# Dependency convergence error with Maven

Tags: java, maven, dropwizard

I am trying to create a REST api server for a NLP library (Illinois NER tagger) using DropWizard. The following is the content of my `.pom` file:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
        <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>CogcompSoftware</id>
        <name>CogcompSoftware</name>
        <url>http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/m2repo/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp</groupId>
        <artifactId>illinois-ner</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.72</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-http2</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-metrics-graphite</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.196</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

On adding the dependency tag and repository tag corresponding to Illinois library my code is crashing with following error on `mvn package`

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce) @ dropwizard-example ---
[WARNING] 
Dependency convergence error for edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-core-utilities:3.0.72 paths to dependency are:
+-io.dropwizard:dropwizard-example:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-ner:3.0.72
    +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-tokenizer:3.0.72
      +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-core-utilities:3.0.72
and
+-io.dropwizard:dropwizard-example:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-ner:3.0.72
    +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-core-utilities:3.0.72
and
+-io.dropwizard:dropwizard-example:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-ner:3.0.72
    +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:LBJava:1.2.24
      +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-inference:0.6.0
        +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-core-utilities:3.0.51
and
+-io.dropwizard:dropwizard-example:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-ner:3.0.72
    +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:LBJava:1.2.24
      +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-inference:0.6.0
        +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-sl-core:1.0.2
          +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-core-utilities:3.0.22
and
+-io.dropwizard:dropwizard-example:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-ner:3.0.72
    +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:LBJava-NLP-tools:1.0.1
      +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-core-utilities:1.2.11

[WARNING] 
Dependency convergence error for edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:LBJava:1.2.24 paths to dependency are:
+-io.dropwizard:dropwizard-example:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-ner:3.0.72
    +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:LBJava:1.2.24
and
+-io.dropwizard:dropwizard-example:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-ner:3.0.72
    +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:LBJava-NLP-tools:1.0.1
      +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:LBJava:1.1.0

[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.DependencyConvergence failed with message:
Failed while enforcing releasability the error(s) are [
Dependency convergence error for edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-core-utilities:3.0.72 paths to dependency are:
+-io.dropwizard:dropwizard-example:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-ner:3.0.72
    +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-tokenizer:3.0.72
      +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-core-utilities:3.0.72
and
+-io.dropwizard:dropwizard-example:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-ner:3.0.72
    +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-core-utilities:3.0.72
and
+-io.dropwizard:dropwizard-example:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-ner:3.0.72
    +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:LBJava:1.2.24
      +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-inference:0.6.0
        +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-core-utilities:3.0.51
and
+-io.dropwizard:dropwizard-example:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-ner:3.0.72
    +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:LBJava:1.2.24
      +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-inference:0.6.0
        +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-sl-core:1.0.2
          +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-core-utilities:3.0.22
and
+-io.dropwizard:dropwizard-example:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-ner:3.0.72
    +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:LBJava-NLP-tools:1.0.1
      +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-core-utilities:1.2.11
, 
Dependency convergence error for edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:LBJava:1.2.24 paths to dependency are:
+-io.dropwizard:dropwizard-example:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-ner:3.0.72
    +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:LBJava:1.2.24
and
+-io.dropwizard:dropwizard-example:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-ner:3.0.72
    +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:LBJava-NLP-tools:1.0.1
      +-edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:LBJava:1.1.0
]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 38.047 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-31T16:36:33+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/1517M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce) on project dropwizard-example: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: You need to lookup your parent pom and check the library dependencies you are using on the dependencyManagement section. Since there are not version tag on many libraries on your pom. I suggest you run a dependency tree in your project you are probably using different versions of libraries that depends on each other.

Comment: I have included the version number of libraries I am using but still I am getting the same error. I have never used parent and dependencyManagement tag in maven can you show how it has to be used in this situation through some code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To resolve the error, you need to manage the version of the conflicting artifacts in your dependencyManagement section.

For example: To solve the issue for `edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-core-utilities` you need to make an entry like

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp</groupId>
   <artifactId>illinois-core-utilities</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.72</version>
</dependency>
```

in your dependencyManagement section.

Comment: There was one dependencyManagement tage already in the pom file. Please have a look I have updated the question. Your suggestion didn't work out, can you suggest something else?

Comment: What do you mean: "didn't work out"? Did you really add all the conflicting dependencies (edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:illinois-core-utilities, edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp:LBJava,...) to your dependencyManagement as entries as I have shown you? Then please edit the question and show the complete pom and the errors you get.